# c# Entity framework's strange behavior with remote mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to use entity framework 6.1.3 to connect with remote MySql server (MySql.Data.Entity 6.9.9). Connection doesn't fails, but my code do unexpected things:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Iqsv.jpg)

It is interesting, that this code run in expected way on my local MySql DB with exactly same schema and exactly same records.
Does anyone have ideas, why code doen't work on remote DB? How to fix this bug?

EDIT:
Code also works fine, for example, with comparing integer primary key. Problem with string comparation? It's easy exetutes ToList() for all records.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with charset. Just add "charset=utf8" (my remote db default charset) to connection string.